# Change line width of lines in matplotlib pyplot legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to change the thickness/width of the line samples featured in the pyplot legend.

Line width of line samples within legend are the same as the lines they represent in the plot (so if line `y1` has `linewidth=7.0`, the legend's corresponding `y1` label will also have `linewidth=7.0`).

I would like the legend lines to be thicker than lines featured in the plot.

For example, the following code generates the following image:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make some data
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)

y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

# plot sin(x) and cos(x)
fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y1, c='b', label='y1',linewidth=7.0)
ax.plot(x, y2, c='r', label='y2')

leg = plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: example code plot]

I want to set the `y1` label in the legend to have `linewidth=7.0`, while the `y1` line featured in the plot has a different width (`linewidth=1.0`).

Related issues had answers for changing the `linewidth` of the legend bounding box through `leg.get_frame().set_linewidth(7.0)`. This does not change `linewidth` of the lines *within* the legend.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

@ImportanceOfBeingErnest 's answer is good if you only want to change the linewidth inside the legend box. But I think it is a bit more complex since you have to copy the handles before changing legend linewidth. Besides, it can not change the legend label fontsize. The following two methods can not only change the linewidth but also the legend label text font size in a more concise way.

#### Method 1

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make some data
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)

y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

# plot sin(x) and cos(x)
fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y1, c='b', label='y1')
ax.plot(x, y2, c='r', label='y2')

leg = plt.legend()
# get the individual lines inside legend and set line width
for line in leg.get_lines():
    line.set_linewidth(4)
# get label texts inside legend and set font size
for text in leg.get_texts():
    text.set_fontsize('x-large')

plt.savefig('leg_example')
plt.show()
```

#### Method 2

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make some data
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)

y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

# plot sin(x) and cos(x)
fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y1, c='b', label='y1')
ax.plot(x, y2, c='r', label='y2')

leg = plt.legend()
# get the lines and texts inside legend box
leg_lines = leg.get_lines()
leg_texts = leg.get_texts()
# bulk-set the properties of all lines and texts
plt.setp(leg_lines, linewidth=4)
plt.setp(leg_texts, fontsize='x-large')
plt.savefig('leg_example')
plt.show()
```

The above two methods produce the same output image:

[image: output image]

Comment: How to set this with `plt.rcParams.update({'legend.linewidth': 10})` since it is not in the keys?

Comment: The matplotlib rc has a setting `legend.fontsize`. Refer to the rc file for more info.