# python matplotlib markerscale for area plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

What I want to do is a plot of generation and demand in an electricity grid with Matplotlib in Python. This is my code:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,8))
generation.plot(kind="area", ax=ax, linewidth=1, alpha=0.9)
load.plot(kind="area", ax=ax, linewidth=1, alpha=0.9)
labels = ['Erzeugung', 'Last']
ax.legend(labels, ncol=4, loc="best", markerscale=10)
ax.set_ylabel("GW")
ax.set_xlabel("")
plt.tight_layout()
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

My question is about the `markerscale`: Why doesn't it work with this kind of plot? The problem is the bad visibility of the marker in the legend, it would be much better with a thicker line or even a box. And this without increasing the line width of the lines. Any ideas?

Comment: And another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42758897/change-line-width-of-lines-in-matplotlib-pyplot-legend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the line size manually after creation as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,8))

generation = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, 14, 10))
load = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2, 5, 10))

generation.plot(kind="area", ax=ax, linewidth=1, alpha=0.9)
load.plot(kind="area", ax=ax, linewidth=1, alpha=0.9)

labels = ['Erzeugung', 'Last']

legend = ax.legend(labels, ncol=4, loc="best")

for handle in legend.legendHandles:
    handle.set_linewidth(3.0)

ax.set_ylabel("GW")
ax.set_xlabel("")
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Giving you something like:

[image: matplotlib with bigger legend line]

Comment: It's always the same: It can be so easy. Thanks a lot !!